# iOS switch back to background UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm looking for a way to present a modal view over my current UIViewController to basically show a UIActivityIndicator and force users to wait while data is being loaded.

in BaseViewController.m (base class of all my UIViewControllers):

```
// show loading view
-(void) showLoading
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    LoadingViewController *loading = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loadingView"];

    loading.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.7];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:loading animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

This works great, but how can I go back to the background view after the loading view should be done?

Need a stopLoading method to go back to the original view:

```
// stop loading
-(void) stopLoading
{
    // code here
}
```

If I try to present a new view after I present the loading view like so:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *view = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loadingView"];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The debugger gives **Warning:**

`Attempt to present PropertyPickerViewController: 0x8af6010  on ViewController: 0x8ab23c0 which is already presenting LoadingViewController: 0x8acf530`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In fact, I'm not sure that it'a great idea to present new controller with animated gif.

The best option is (imo) show `UIActivityIndicator + place a view on top on all other views to prevent user from clicking anything`.

Comment: Well, the gif is a UIActivityIndicator. I'll edit my question to portray that. Also, this worked perfectly. I will accept answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You must `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` first.

Check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW103).